# Temp table - group by - delete - keep top 10

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, sql-delete

I have a temp table with 50 000 records. If I do a `GROUP BY`, with COUNT, it will look like this:

```
+--------+--------+
|GrpById | Count  |
+--------+--------+
| 1      | 10000  |
| 2      |  8000  |
| 3      | 12000  |
| 4      |  9000  |
| 5      | 11000  |
+--------+--------+
```

I would like to delete some records, so from each Id's (1,2,3,4,5) I would have only 10 records left after deletion.

So eventually If I would make a new `GROUP BY` with COUNT, I would have something like this:

```
+--------+--------+
|GrpById | Count  |
+--------+--------+
| 1      |    10  |
| 2      |    10  |
| 3      |    10  |
| 4      |    10  |
| 5      |    10  |
+--------+--------+
```

Can I do it without `FETCH NEXT` ?

Comment: Top 10 sorted by what? Note Martin's answer last sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just preserve an arbitrary 10 per group you can use

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GrpById ORDER BY GrpById) AS RN
FROM YourTable
)
DELETE FROM 
CTE WHERE RN > 10;
```

Change the `ORDER BY` if you need something less arbitrary.

Comment: @Ash as a stand alone statement it is not required in SQL Server. The code in the answer will execute fine without it. You need to ensure that any preceding statement is terminated with a `;` before the `with` though.

Comment: I was joking :-) Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @id int;
declare @count int;
set @id =1;
select @count=count(1) from table where id = @id

delete top(@count-10) from table where id = @id
```

Try the above query for all values if id in variable @id